# What happens if ConsumerRecordRecoverer in SeekToCurrentErrorHandler throws exception

Tags: spring-kafka

I am just wondering what if ConsumerRecordRecoverer in SeekToCurrentErrorHandler throws exception? I saw the code and according to my understanding if this happens the record will replayed again. Is my understanding right?

Is there a way to better handle this? Like catching that specific exception when recoverer fails and logging that and capturing that metrics and move on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct; the framework can't make any assumptions here so it takes the conservative approach if the recoverer fails to "recover" the record and it is replayed.

In many cases (e.g. failure to publish the failure to a dead letter topic) this would be the desired behavior.

If that's not what you want, you need to put the logic in the recoverer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wrote an implementation of ConsumerRecordRecoverer and there I am handling the exception when recovery itself would fail.

Comment: Don't reties caused by failures in recoverer lead to potential infinite loop situation?